# Set arbitrary or random computer name when connecting to public wifi

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi, networkmanager, hostname

I am not sure about the correct terminology of what I want to achieve. Here is a hand-waving description:

When connecting to a (usually) public WIFI spot, I want that spot to not know my computer name / hostname at all. I want the WIFI to see a different computer name every time I connect to it.

I have managed to send a different/random MAC address to the WIFI spot (spoof or clone MAC) each time I connect using `GNU macchanger` but I can't find anything relating to cloning or spoofing my hostname and send that to the WIFI spot, **without having to change my actual hostname**. I still want to type `hostname` at the prompt and get the hostname I usually have.

The random hostname can be anything really, i.e. it can be created programmatically by NetworkManager or other -- I do not need to specify that. All I need is to connect with a different name. I don't want to give away anything about my computer identity (yes I know!).

I use Fedora34 and NetworkManager and I test what the WIFI spot sees from me by connecting to my smartphone in hotspot mode.

btw, is "hostname" the correct term for what the WIFI spot sees when I connect to it? I can't seem to find many pointers relating to spoofing my `hostname`.

Comment: What happens if you set `dhcp-send-hostname=false` (`man nm-settings`) https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Turn_off_hostname_sending

Comment: nothing, still my hostname is shown (as I said, i test it by connecting to my smartphone hotspot and check the connected devices there). What I did was to edit ```/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XYZ.nmconnection``` and added ```dhcp-send-hostname=false``` under sections ```[ipv4]``` and ```[ipv6]```, as you suggested. NetworkManager version ```1.30.4-1.fc34``` (XYZ being the name of the WIFI I connect to smartphone etc.). I also restarted nm using ```systemctl restart NetworkManager```, but did not reboot.

Comment: I have filed an issue with NetworkManager at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/857

Comment: Relevant issue with NM https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/906